# Getting day difference between two dates in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql, triggers

I want to get the day difference between 2 dates in Oracle trigger.Here's my code: (declare v_dayDiff number)

```
--in my trigger
     SELECT View_Table.DateStart - View_Table.DateFinish
     INTO v_dayDiff
     FROM View_Table
     WHERE :NEW.id=View_Table.id;
```

DATEDIFF() is not working and in the forums I read that we cane use it with SELECT, but it's not working

Comment: DATEDIFF is used in SQL Server, MySQL, DB2, PostgreSQL, and perhaps other databases, but not in Oracle.

Comment: Neither Postgres nor DB2 have a predefined  DateDiff function.

Comment: @Belayer: I was relying on web searches. Looks like that may not be 100% accurate. :-)

Comment: You might find it useful to look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, the difference between two dates is decimal days.  So, your logic should work, although presumably you want the value to be positive.  So assuming that finish is after the start:

```
SELECT View_Table.DateFinish - View_Table.DateStart
```

Then if you want an integer, truncate the value:

```
SELECT TRUNC(View_Table.DateFinish - View_Table.DateStart)
```